# Aptana Studio 3 - unable to remote debug rails app deployed on virtualbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, aptana, remote-debugging

Hello I have problem to remote debugging rails app (deployed on vagrant vm) in Aptana 3.

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'linecache19', :git => 'git://github.com/mark-moseley/linecache'
gem 'ruby-debug-base19x', '~> 0.11.30.pre4'
gem 'ruby-debug19',:require => 'ruby-debug'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.9.0'
  gem 'rb-inotify', '0.8.8'
  gem 'libnotify', '0.5.9'
  gem "watchr", "~> 0.7"
  gem 'guard-rspec', '0.5.5'
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'annotate', '~> 2.4.1.beta'
  gem 'sextant'
end


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'therubyracer'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'spork', '~> 0.9.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.4.0'
end

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'
```

rails s -u:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
=> Debugger enabled
[2012-06-01 06:41:48] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-06-01 06:41:48] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2011-10-30) [i686-linux]
[2012-06-01 06:41:48] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=14225 port=3000
```

so debug mode is enabled

In Aptana 3:

Debug -> Debug Configurations -> Remote Ruby Debug Sessions, create new with:

```
host: localhost
port: 3000
```

Tried to run 'Debug' but I still get Problem occured dialog with 'An internal error occurred during: "Launching rails".
null'

Any idea what to do to enable aptana 3 remote debugging?

Thank you.

Comment: I have same problem with Ruby 1.9.3 and "debugger" gem. WebBrick raise the "ERROR bad URI" with the path to breakpoint. I really hope someone can help us solve this issue...

Comment: I opened a ticket in Aptana issue tracker:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-7308